# Implementing a Trie in Python using lists alone

Tags: python, linked-list, trie

I've been working on implementing a Trie in Python for educational purposes. I tried implementing one using dictionaries and I was successful.

The structure of a trie with the words `in`, `inn`, `inner`, `innerr` would be as follows:

```
[['i', [['n', [['n', [['e', [['r', [['r', [], 'end']], 'end']]]], 'end']], 'end']]]]
```

where `end` indicates the end of a word.

```
class TrieException(Exception):
    pass

def add_word(word, trie):
    END = "end"
    if word == '':
        raise TrieException("word empty")

    prev = None
    branch = trie

    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        found = False
        for each in branch:
            if each[0] == c:
                if i == len(word)-1:
                    if len(each) > 2:
                        raise TrieException("Word already present")
                    else:
                        each.append(END)
                prev = branch
                branch = each[1]
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            nb = []
            if i == len(word)-1:
                branch.append([c, nb, END])
            else:
                branch.append([c, nb])
            branch = nb

def search_word(word, trie):
    if word == '':
        raise TrieException("empty word")

    branch = trie
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        found = False
        for each in branch:
            if each[0] == c:
                found = True
                branch = each[1]
                if i == len(word)-1:
                    if len(each) <= 2:
                        raise TrieException("Word not found")
                break
        if not found:
            raise TrieException("Word not found")
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this in a cleaner fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use generic-yet-novel exceptions like `TrieException` - it tells you nothing you didn't already know. Rather, reuse standard exceptions to give the user some way of distinguishing errors based off of *meaning*:

```
raise ValueError("word empty")
raise KeyError("Word already present")
raise ValueError("empty word")
raise KeyError("Word not found")
```

Note that your formatting is not standardized; some start with an uppercase and other identical errors have the word-order switched. This should be fixed:

```
raise ValueError("inserting empty word")
raise KeyError("word already present")
raise KeyError("word not found")
```

Note that a trie is basically a `set`, so you should probably try and copy the `set` interface. As such, there's little reason to not support having empty words and one would expect adding a key that already exists to be a silent operation (no error thrown).

Your version doesn't seem to offer support for empty strings, so let's re-examine. There are two common ways of supporting empty strings. The first is a format where the nodes have a boolean tagging whether they are terminal. This would look like:

```
    [False, · ]
            |
          (a,·)
            |
    [False, · ]
            |
          (n,·)
            |
    [False, · , · ]
           /     \
        (a,·)   (n,·)
         /         \
      [True] [True, · , · ]
                   /     \
                (a,·)   (e,·)
                /          \
             [True]       [True]
```

to store `[ana, ann, anna, anne]`.

An alternative is doing away with those altogether and storing strings of the form `[ana$, ann$, anna$, anne$]` where the `$` is a not a character but an end-of-string marker. This would give:

```
          [ · ]
            |
          (a,·)
            |
          [ · ]
            |
          (n,·)
            |
        [ · , · ]
         /     \
      (a,·)   (n,·)
       /         \
    [ · ]   [ · , · , · ]
     /       /    |    \
  ($,·)   ($,·) (a,.) (e,·)
   /       /      |      \
 [ ]     [ ]    [ · ]   [ · ]
                  |        \  
                ($,·)     ($,·)
                  |         |
                 [ ]       [ ]
```

This is perhaps the one you were trying to do with your `'end'` string, but yours looks like

```
          [ · ]
            |
          [a,·]
            |
          [ · ]
            |
          [n,·]
            |
        [ · , · ]
         /     \
     (a,·,$) (n,·,$)
      /          \
    [ ]       [ . , · ]
               /     \
           (a,·,$) (e,·,$)
             /         \
           [ ]         [ ]
```

Note that you put the end marker in the edge with the previous character, not on its own. This adds more complexity to the design over the other options, and doesn't allow containing an empty string.

So let's reconsider the code

```
def add_word(word, trie):
    END = "end"
```

Note that `UPPER_CASE` is generally for global constants, which this should really be.

```
    if word == '':
        raise ValueError("inserting empty word")
```

We can discard this now, but note that `not word` would be more idiomatic.

```
    prev = None
    branch = trie
```

Note that `current_branch` or `subtrie` would be more descriptive.

```
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
```

You don't need to check `if i == len(word)-1` if you're just adding a `$` on the end. However, you don't need that anyway due to the `else` block for loops:

```
for i in j:
    if p(i):
        break
else:
    print("Didn't break")
```

Overall it looks like

```
def add_word(word, trie):
    subtrie = trie

    for c in word:
        for each in subtrie:
            if each[0] == c:
                subtrie = each[1]
                break
        else:
            nb = []
            subtrie.append([c, nb])
            subtrie = nb

    for each in subtrie:
        if each[0] == END:
            break
    else:
        subtrie.append([END, []])
```

You can use unpacking to get

```
...
for edge, node in subtrie:
    if edge == c:
        subtrie = node
        break
...
for edge, _ in subtrie:
    if edge == END:
        break
...
```

You can use `any` for the later:

```
if not any(edge == END for edge, _ in subtrie):
    subtrie.append([END, []])
```

and you can even use `next` for the former:

```
try:
    subtrie = next(node for edge, node in subtrie if edge == c)
except StopIteration:
    nb = []
    subtrie.append([c, nb])
    subtrie = nb
```

It'd be a neat idea to actually use dictionaries here, but if not one can at least use sorting and `bisect`. This would be better if `END` sorted nicely, so I'll change it to the empty string. This gives

```
from bisect import bisect_left

END = ''

def add_word(word, trie):
    subtrie = trie

    for char in word:
        index = bisect_left(subtrie, [char])

        if index < len(subtrie) and subtrie[index][0] == char:
            subtrie = subtrie[index][1]
        else:
            new_branch = []
            subtrie.insert(index, [char, new_branch])
            subtrie = new_branch

    if not (subtrie and subtrie[0][0] == END):
        subtrie.append([END, []])
```

`search_word` should really be called `assert_word`; it doesn't actually have an interface optimized for searching for words. I suppose you actually wanted something akin to `__contains__`, so `contains_word` would be appropriate if it actually returned its value.

The first lot of simplifications leads to

```
def contains_word(word, trie):
    subtrie = trie

    for char in word:
        for edge, node in subtrie:
            if edge == char:
                subtrie = node
                break
        else:
            return False

    return subtrie and subtrie[0][0] == END
```

and using `bisect` gets

```
def contains_word(word, trie):
    subtrie = trie

    for char in word:
        index = bisect_left(subtrie, [char])

        if not (index < len(subtrie) and subtrie[index][0] == char):
            return False

        subtrie = subtrie[index][1]

    return subtrie and subtrie[0][0] == END
```

You should consider making `trie` the first argument - it's a `self`-like argument so normally should be at the start.

Finally, consider replacing the edges with tuples, since their length is always `2`.

Answer (score 2):

### Exceptions are for exceptional (read 'rare','unexpected') edge cases

You are using exceptions as the default behaviour, this is not nice, instead functions should return values, remove `TrieException("word not find")` from `search_word(word, trie)` and instead return True if you find the word and False if you do not find it.

### Confusing alias

```
branch = trie
```

You just confuse the reader, each thing should have one name only.

Comment: I disagree with both explanations; Python has a well known EAFTP preference and aliases are fine. I agree with these *in context*, though; I just don't think the explanations make it clear why.

Comment: @Veedrac I am interested in your comment? How should I change the explanations in your opinion?

Comment: For the first point, I would mention what you *should* do (have a well-defined interface that matches the name - use errors on failure to do that task). For the second, after doing a proper read of the code I think aliasing is appropriate, but the name it's aliased to is bad. I make similar points in my answer ("Note that `current_branch` or `subtrie` would be more descriptive." and "`search_word` should really be called `assert_word`").